# ASP IF statement to get data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to write an "if" statment in asp to get the data in the correct format that I need to feed in a highchart.

Question 1: Can you guys let me know whats wrong with my if statement? 
Question 2: If i want to add another data set to feed in another chart for condition 0, how do I reference that in the asp?And where do I put another sql statement?

```vb
condition = Split(Request.Form("condition"),"~")
    'condition = Split("field1~field2~field3~('field4')~('')~('Field5')~'01/18/2015' and '02/02/2015'~field6", "~")

    '0 is the chart type
    '1 is chart frequency
    '2 company
    '3 is place
    '4 is shop
    '5 is caused
    '6 is date range'
    '7is top5 type'
    'field7~('')~('')~('')~01/18/2015<>01/18/2015~field8'


''  Response.write condition(3)

    chartinfo = condition(2)
    dateString = ""

    if condition(0)<>"Top 5" then
        where = "[Type]='" + condition(1) +"'"

        if condition(1)<> "Monthly" then 
            where = where + " and convert(datetime,date,101) between " + condition(6)
        end if
        if condition(3) <>"('')" then
            where = where + " and place in " + condition(3)
            chartinfo = chartinfo + ";" + condition(3)
        end if
        if condition(4) <>"('')" then
            where = where + " and Shop in " + condition(4)
            chartinfo = chartinfo + ";" + condition(4)
        end if
        if condition(5) <>"('')" then
            where = where + " and [Caused Group] in " + condition(5)
            chartinfo = chartinfo + ";" + condition(5)
        end if

    else
        condition(0) = "Top 5" then
        where 
    end if

    where = replace(where,"'","''")

    sql = "[Data] '" + where + "', '''" + dateString +"''','''"+ chartinfo +"'''"
```

Comment: 1. Something weird at `else` place. Could be `elseif condition(0) = "Top 5" then` or retain `else` and comment `'''condition(0) = "Top 5" then` line. And what do you mean by detached `where`? Proper indentation should help.

Comment: xcuse - so dirty code

Answer (score 0):

```
where = "[Type]='" + condition(1) +"'" 
--> 
where = " where [Type] = '" + condition(1) +"'" 

..skip..

else 
   condition(0) = "Top 5" then 
   where 
--> 

else 
 ' condition(0) = "Top 5" then 
   where = ""
```

Comment: I think this answer could be a little better if you gave context to the code you are using. Are you trying to suggest substitutions for current lines?